# Android's ContentProvider Uri changes notifications scheme

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

Let's say i have this UriMatcher (found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html):

```
sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people", PEOPLE);
sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people/#", PEOPLE_ID);
sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people/#/phones", PEOPLE_PHONES);
sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people/#/phones/#", PEOPLE_PHONES_ID);
sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "people/#/phones/special", SPECIAL);
sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "phones", PHONES);
sURIMatcher.addURI("contacts", "phones/#", PHONES_ID);
```

I have the usual ContentProvider:

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri...){
   cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
}
@Override
public int update(Uri uri...){
   getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
}
```

The problem is, when I update something with this Uri: `phones/<id>`, I want these Uri: `people/<peopleId>/phones`, `people/<peopleId>/phones/<id>` and `people/<peopleId>/phones/special` to also be notified of changes!

I made some tests, and it does not...
I don't know what to to do...
Many thanks.

Comment: so you know an ID, right? then based on that ID construct the `Uri`s you want and call `notifyChange` with them

Comment: Yeah, I know the Phone ID, but not the People ID...

Comment: i dont get it at all, so what uri of type `people/<peopleId>/phones` you want to notify? all `people/*` ? or all `people/*/phones` ?

Comment: Yes, all `people/#/phones`, when I edit a phone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have a peopleId, the only thing you can do is notify on `people`. In fact, Android's ContactsProvider does something similar -- every change notifies `content://com.android.contacts`, regardless what changed.

Comment: Knowing that AOSP is doing it like this is very comforting thank you.